# Bazaar unrecognised value for BZR_SSH

Tags: bazaar

I have tried out bzr-2.5.1-1-setup as well as bzr-2.6b1-1-setup.

Also I set the variable: BZR_SSH to C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\PLINK.EXE (here is the putty software located).

I always get the message: Unrecognised value for BZR_SSH environment variable: `c:\Program Files (x86)\putty\PLINK.EXE`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, BZR_SSH may only accept values like `ssh` and `plink` and then bzr relies on the corresponding executables being found on the PATH.